# Why can't the type of std::initializer_list be deducted in such a case?

Tags: c++, templates, standards, c++17, type-deduction

```
template<typename T>
void f(T)
{}

int main()
{
    auto coll = { 1, 2, 3 };
    f(coll); // ok
    f({ 1, 2, 3 }); // error
}
```

My compiler is `clang 5.0`.

The error message is as follows:

> f({ 1, 2, 3 }); // error : no matching function for call to 'f'
>
> note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'

**Why is that `f(coll)` is ok but `f({ 1, 2, 3 })` is not?**